# Background Animado em CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Andei pesquisando em CSS como colocar um fundo animado. No codepen o que achei não funcionou, eu gostaria de fazer algo parecido com isso : https://codepen.io/vaibhavarora/pen/xmpxjp
ou isso: https://discordapp.com/login

Mas no fundo, deixar uma imagem de fundo da minha escolha ao invés do azul, alguém tem algum tutorial ou algo básico no com css para que eu consiga iniciar o funcionamento disto?

Comment: Cara edita sua pergunta e coloca o que vc já tem de código ai. Outra coisa, não entendo direito o que vc quer, tem uma imagem do layout que vc pretende? Vc que aquela forma por cima de uma imagem no background? Coloque ai seu HTML e CSS que tem até o momento

Comment: Na realidade, não é "fundo animado". É um objeto com animação como qualquer outro. Depois basta você posicionar onde quiser. Seja de fundo ou não. No mais, o @hugocsl já descreveu o que vc precisa fazer...

Comment: eu não fiz nada, porque não sei pro onde começar

Comment: @LipESprY na verdade pode ser um "fundo animado" sim! Depois da uma olhada na resposta que deixei 

Comment: @hugocsl Já falei que não te subestimo, né?! Kkkk

Comment: @LipESprY o StackOverflow é onde da para fazer tudo que vc não tem a chance de fazer em outros projetos rss... Mas em breve vc vai pode exercitar bastante por aqui!

Comment: @hugocsl Confesso que tem sido mais didático solucionar os problemas aqui do que muitos cursinhos e tutoriais que vejo por aí! Kkkkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue uma opção direto no `body` usando apenas o `background`, nem precisa de tags `html` :D

Tudo apenas com `CSS`:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-image: 
        radial-gradient(circle at left bottom, 
        #ffff 0%, #ffff 20%, 
        #fffb 20%, #fffb 30%, 
        #fff6 30%, #fff6 40%, 
        #fff2 40%, #fff2 50%, 
        transparent 50%, transparent 100%),
        url(https://placecage.com/100/100);
    background-size: 100% 100%, cover;
    background-position: bottom left, center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    animation: nome 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes nome {
    50% {
        background-size: 120% 120%, cover;
    }
}
```

Comment: hugo, como eu diminuo um pouco o raio dos circulos? Ta quase no meio da tela :)

Comment: @RicardoGonçalves coloca aqui `background-size: 60% 60%, cover;` e dentro do @keyframes vc coloca `background-size: 100% 100%, cover;` isso vai resolver, a não ser que a tela seja muito wide... ai vc vai ter que trabalhar nos valores dentro do radial-gradiente, que é um pouco mais chato de mudar para quem não tem muita familiaridade...

Comment: a última Hugo, como eu consigo deixar esses círculos um pouco transparentes? vai fica perfeito com a minha ideia :)

Comment: @RicardoGonçalves ta vendo que eu estou usando no radial-gradiente uma cor em hexadecimal que tem 4 digitos? Tipo #fffb ou #fff6, esse último caractere controla a opacidade é só trocar esse último caractere que fica mais ou menos transparente. Vc pode ler mais aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/345285/css-opacidade-da-cor-pelo-hexadecimal/345312#345312 ... A outra opção é trocar a cor hexa #fffa por cores em rgba(), ai vc tira o #fffb e coloca rgba(255,255,255,0.2), esse 0.2 no final controla a transparencia da cor, 1 é totalmente visível, e 0 é transparente, ai vai 0.1, 0.5, até 1

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando esse [snippet do codepen](https://codepen.io/vaibhavarora/pen/xmpxjp) que você forneceu na pergunta, basta alterar a propriedade `background` da tag `<body>` para incluir uma imagem, ao invés da cor azul que está agora.

```css
body {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract')/* única alteração. */
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  animation: ripple 15s infinite;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #508fb9;
}

.small {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: -100px;
  bottom: -100px;
}

.medium {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  left: -200px;
  bottom: -200px;
}

.large {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  left: -300px;
  bottom: -300px;
}

.xlarge {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  left: -400px;
  bottom: -400px;
}

.xxlarge {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  left: -500px;
  bottom: -500px;
}

.shade1 {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.shade2 {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.shade3 {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.shade4 {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.shade5 {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='ripple-background'>
  <div class='circle xxlarge shade1'></div>
  <div class='circle xlarge shade2'></div>
  <div class='circle large shade3'></div>
  <div class='circle mediun shade4'></div>
  <div class='circle small shade5'></div>
</div>
```